# A complete classification of linear foliations of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

A linear $1$-form  on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a  $1$-form $\alpha=\sum_i P_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)dx_i$ such that each $P_i$ is in the linear form $P_i=\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$. A linear foliation of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ is  a  foliation tangent to the kernel of  a linear $1$-form $\alpha$ whose  corresponding matrix $(\alpha_{ij})$ is  a  non singular matrix.

As I learned from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282911/a-possible-sub-riemannian-structure-associated-to-a-non-symmetric-matrix/282984#282984), there are linear $1$-forms which are  Frobenius integrable but are not closed $1$-form.

> For  $n>2$, is there  a  complete  classification  and  dynamical description  of all linear foliations? In particular, is there a  linear foliation of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ which has a (compact) leaf with non trivial holonomy?

I think that this situation can not occurs  when the  corresponding $1$-form $\alpha= \sum_i \sum_j(a_{ij}x_j)dx_i $ is  a closed $1$-form.(Equivalently the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is a symmetric matrix)

Comment: Is $\alpha$ assumed to be regular outside $0$ ?

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  Yes it is  assumed that the  matrix $(\alpha_{ij})$ is  a  non singular matrix. I revise the question to emphasis this regularity.

Comment: Actually, I gave the classification of the cases in which the foliation is integrable in the answer that you cite.  The answer is that these are exactly either the closed 1-forms or the non-closed ones that can be pulled back by a linear projection to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  You should be able to deduce the holonomy of the leaves directly from this.  In fact, it follows immediately from the fact that the holonomy will be the same as the holonomy in the $2$-dimensional case, namely that it is trivial because it's trivial there.

Comment: @RobertBryant  I try to  deduce this  from your  answer to my previous question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know offhand the answer of your first question, but I can answer the particular situation you describe afterwards : the holonomy is always trivial.

First, notice that  a compact leaf $L$ is everywhere transverse to the radial vector field $R$ (if a ray $x\mathbb R_{>0}$ were tangent to $L$ then it would be included in $L$, breaking compactness). This implies that $L$ meets any such ray exactly once : it is diffeomorphic to a $(n-1)$-sphere.

Now, every rescaling $\lambda L$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb R^\times$ is also a compact leaf, thus $\alpha$ foliates the space with smooth spheres. The foliation is therefore smoothly equivalent to the boring trivial fibration $\mathbb R_{>0}\times\mathbb S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your  answer. But  I think that  some thing is  missing in the  second paragraph "A  compact leaf  can exist if  the  corresponding  matrix has no real  eigenvalue".  For example, let $n=2$  The  identity  matrix  gives  $xdx+ydy=0$ which gives   foliation  by circle.

Comment: A real  eigenspace  of $A$  is  invariant under the flow  of  1  dimensional foliation defined  by $X'=AX$. But  I am  considering a  different object. Right?

Comment: Sure, I'm too used to dealing with vector fields ;) I'll remove that part of my answer, which is not relevant anyway (see the edit).

Comment: Why does transversality of the compact leaf with radial direction imply that the leaf is diffeomorphic to sphere? Is not possible  that we embed a tori in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with transverse intersection with radial direction?

Comment: Well, no, it's not possible to embed a torus in such a way. Try a connectedness argument.

Comment: Very interesting point. But is there an abstract proof?This is  the problem: Let M  be a submanifol of $\mathbb{R}^3$ diffeomorphic to tori. Prove that the radial vector field must be tangent at some point. Can one prove this statent via the  following processes? The integral of $i_ R \Omega$ over such M should vanish. Where $\Omega$ is the standard volum form of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $R$ is the radial vector field?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your latter question.